# How do I help an injured plant avoid infection?

Tags: botany

A hail storm came through my town while I was at work and my innocent cactus was outside! I'm pretty sure this exists, but is there something I can put on these open wounds to stop them from rotting/getting infected?

[image]

I would like to point out that I did try to google this, and I was unable to find an answer, which is why I'm here.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for [Gardening.SE]. If you agree that is a better site for your question, please delete your post from here before reposting there because [cross-posting is impolite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/797607). Alternatively, you can request migration of this question by flagging your post for moderator intervention and explaining what you want and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Petroleum jelly thin coat with clean fingers would work in my opinion.